# .htaccess: how to specify how many times user can input wrong credentials before 401 error/redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

On an Apache webserver I am protecting a directory with a .htaccess file.
How can I specify after HOW MANY wrong credential entries the server aborts login and throws a 401 error or redirects the user to another page?

Thanks
AO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have to be done programmatically, likely in your PHP Code.

Here are a couple pages that may help:

- Protect Wordpress Against Brute Force Attack (addresses some security issues in htaccess) - http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/news/general/wp-login-brute-force-attack
- Here is a method to implement a failed login count using Agiletoolkit - [Agiletoolkit Maximum number of failed login attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188514/agiletoolkit-maximum-number-of-failed-login-attempts)